# How to run a timer in an separate thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I have a loop like below

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    // some long time processing
}
```

I want to create a timer, which would check if one processing runs more than 5 minutes. If one processing runs more than 5 minutes, it would stop current processing then start another processing.

Is it possible to make another thread to monitor the main loop?

My program is a console application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx)

Comment: Actually it's `System.Timers.Timer`

Comment: what is the different between the System.Timers.timer and System.Threading.Timer

Comment: System.Timers.Timer is the IComponent (designer drag-drop) version of System.Threading.Timer - http://mark.michaelis.net/Blog/SystemWindowsFormsTimerVsSystemThreadingTimerVsSystemTimersTimer.aspx

Comment: @Richard, no that is form.timers

Comment: @Yongwei, I would say the timers.timer one but I might be wrong

Comment: @Fredou, I think you are right, I did a simple test. It's great.

Comment: @Fredou, no Form.Timers runs on the UI thread. System.Timers.Timer extends Component and thus is available for drag-drop.

Comment: @richard, I might be wrong but I think that forms.timer will wait if the UI hang, not the system.timers.timer

Comment: Timers.Timer and Threading.Timer both run on a separate thread (not the UI thread). However, Timers.Timer extends Component so is still available for drag-drop in the design time environment.

Comment: @richard, I just tried with form.timers and it ignore the UI thread if it hang. my mistake

Comment: i'm currently looking at both in reflector to see how they work

Comment: An explanation of the different timer types: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx

Comment: This does NOT work, nor does it answer the question which is about how to create a timer on a second thread.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [ManualResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx) and specifically the [WaitOne](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190477.aspx) method.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Jamie's asnwer you can use the [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx), which will execute in a background thread.

Answer (score 0):

However, you are still not really able to abort the running code.
The code iteself has to provide an ability to cancel itself which the timer could invoke after a certain time.

You could use a boolean "shouldCancel" for example which you are checking in every iteration of your loop (or even multiple times).

The "bad" way would be using Thread.Abort - however, this is not really good style.